# Scipy griddata doesn't work inside a loop / memory leak

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am having a problem using Scipy's griddata inside a loop. Basically what happens is that the memory grows without bound while the loop is running.

To reproduce the problem just put the example in

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html

inside a loop:

```
for i in range(100000):

    grid_z1 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
```

My Python version is 2.7.3, my numpy version is 1.7.0 and my scipy version is 0.12.0b1. I'm running it on WIndows 7.

Is this a bug? How can I repeat the interpolation many times without incurring in a memory leak problem?

With the rest of the code:

```
def func(x, y):
    return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j]
points = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])

for i in range(100000):

    grid_z1 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your entire loop.

Comment: It's as shown in the original question.

Comment: Could you please edit this into your question? It's really hard to read.

Comment: Data point: I ran your example on Python 2.6.6, numpy 1.6.1, scipy 0.10.1, Windows 7, and there was no memory leak.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a bug with newest versions of numpy/scipy. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Maybe memory leak is not the correct expression, but don't you observe the memory increasing while the loop is running? Should't it keep constant throughout, as grid_z1 is being replaced in every iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [bug in Cython](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.cython.devel/14711), should be worked around in Scipy's final 0.12.0 release.