# Memory Leak in SciPy griddata (Ver. 0.12.0)

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am using scipy.interpolate.griddata in a loop and it is causing Python to accumulate memory with each loop. This is using Python 2.7.5 and SciPy 0.12.0 (installed through Macports) on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

This code below, adapted from the scipy.interpolate.griddata reference guide, illustrates my point.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

def func(x, y):
    return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j]
points = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])

for t in xrange(10000):
    griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
    griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
    griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
```

As I increase the loop, Python will consume more memory.

```
loop      memory
1        48.4 MB
10       52.7 MB
100      94.6 MB
1000    500.9 MB
```

I am not sure if this is the intended behaviour of griddata, nor am I certain that this does not happen in past versions of SciPy. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436074/scipy-griddata-doesnt-work-inside-a-loop-memory-leak), there is a memory leak associated with Cython (I am using ver. 0.19.1), but it should have been resolved in the final release of SciPy 0.12.0.

I appreciate any suggestions on how I can fix or workaround this issue, or any advice if I'm doing something wrong. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2):

If still important, the problem is that scipy 0.12.0 and 0.12.1 has probably been released without cython recompilation of the relevant files.

So the following worked for me:

First updating cython to the most recent version 0.19.2, then recompiling scipy from sources (but the ones from github, not from .tar.gz):

```
git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
cd scipy
git checkout maintenance/0.12.x
python setup.py build
cd ..
pip install -U ./scipy
```

Then the example from the post works without leaking.

UPDATE: Actually I've realised that by mistake did /0.13.x branch instead -- the /0.12.x  still shows the memory leak...