# Memory issues with cartopy.vector_transform.vector_scalar_to_grid

Tags: python, out-of-memory, cartopy

I'm adding wind arrows over wind speed pcolormesh plots. These look good and are almost exactly how I want them to look. Unfortunately as I loop over multiple levels, forecast times etc. the memory usage builds up to the point where the machine crashes.

This does not happen when I do not do the calculations for the wind arrows. The problem is present in the following code:

```
#!/usr/local/sci/bin/python

'''
Created on Jul 18, 2014

@author: freb
'''

import numpy as np

import cartopy
from cartopy.vector_transform import vector_scalar_to_grid

input_coord_system = cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()

this_plot_projection =  cartopy.crs.PlateCarree()

x_start = -180.0
x_end = 180.0
n_x = 500
d_x = (x_end - x_start) / n_x

y_start = -90.0
y_end = 90.0
n_y = 400
d_y = (y_end - y_start) / n_y



n_runs = 10

for i_run in range(n_runs):

    print 'vector_scalar_to_grid call number %s' % i_run
    random_u_data = np.random.randn(n_y, n_x)
    random_v_data = np.random.randn(n_y, n_x)
    random_spd_data = np.sqrt( random_u_data**2 + random_v_data**2)             

    source_lon = np.arange(x_start, x_end, d_x)
    source_lat = np.arange(y_start, y_end, d_y)

    regrid_shape = (60, 40)

    #import pdb #@@@
    #pdb.set_trace() #@@@
    #print 'stop here' #@@@

    (vt_lon, vt_lat, vt_u, vt_v, vt_spd) = vector_scalar_to_grid(input_coord_system,     \
                            this_plot_projection, \
                            regrid_shape, \
                            source_lon, source_lat, \
                            random_u_data, \
                            random_v_data, \
                            random_spd_data )

    print vt_lon.shape, vt_lat.shape, vt_u.shape, vt_v.shape, vt_spd.shape
```

Am I doing anything wrong? or is this a cartopy bug?

Thanks,

Malcolm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce a memory issue using in my environment. I' using:

- numpy v1.8.1
- scipy v0.14.0
- cython v0.20.1
- cartopy (master)

The transform code uses the griddata routine from scipy, I've seen reports of this suffering a memory leak in the past (e.g., [Scipy griddata doesn't work inside a loop / memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436074/scipy-griddata-doesnt-work-inside-a-loop-memory-leak)). I suspect this is the problem, but I don't know if it was fixed in scipy, cython or both... Which package versions are you using?

(Edit: I forgot to mention, I'm using scipy/cython etc. from the conda package manager)

Comment: That's interesting. We're on: Numpy 1.7.2,  Cartopy 0.11.0, and Cipy 0.12.0

Comment: Upgrading to Scipy 0.14.0 seems to fix the problem. Thanks for your help.